# Odd behaviour when updating TableCell in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

I noticed an odd behaviour when scrolling and clicking inside my TableView.

Basically every cell with text "Missing" should have a red font color. When starting the application, everything is fine and working:
[Base Case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZbJP.png)

After double-clicking a checkbox and scrolling up (now the first line is in the view) the font of the first line is red:
[First line red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lorjs.png)

After scrolling back down, the font of the last line is red:
[Last line red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ARJAv.png)

That's the code I am using:

```
    tcAddressAlias.setCellFactory(tc -> new TableCell<Account, String>() {
        @Override
        protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);

            if (!empty) {
                Account a = getTableView().getItems().get(getIndex());

                if(a.getAddress() != null) {
                    setText(item);
                } else {
                    setText("Missing");
                    setStyle("-fx-text-fill: red");
                }
            }
        }
    });

    tcAddressAlias.setCellValueFactory(tc -> 
        Optional.ofNullable(tc.getValue().getAddress())
        .map(add -> new SimpleStringProperty(add.getAlias()))
        .orElseGet(() -> new SimpleStringProperty(""))
    );
```

I already tried debugging, but everything seems to be fine...

Comment: Can't tell for sure having the code given but I think the problem is that once you setStyle it remains there. Try removing it explicitly when cell has proper value.

Comment: @michelson is correct - you never change the style back. You also need to handle the case where the cell is empty (clear the style and set the text to “”)

Comment: Also, why are you jumping through all those hoops? Isn't `a.getAddress()` just `item`? What is the `cellValueFactory` on `tcAddressAlias`?

Comment: @James_D Item is a String. I added the cellValueFactory to my post.

Comment: Something looks weird here. Are you actually adding `null` items to the table's list?

Comment: @James_D I'm adding SimpleStringProperty("")

Comment: No, I was asking if you ever add null items to the table’s items list. If not, there’s no need for that optional and creating a specific value for null.

Comment: @James_D Ahh yes, I'm adding null values to the table's items list.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @michelson!
I added

```
setStyle(null);
```

Example:

```
                if(a.getAddress != null) {
                    setText(item);
                    setStyle(null);
                } else {
                    setText("Missing");
                    setStyle("-fx-text-fill: red");
                }
```